# angularjs ui-router passing dynamic data from form field into resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use resolve in order to ensure that data has been loaded prior to a view state displaying on screen. This resolve is dependent on a selection which the user will have made in a previous state.

As such, I need to perform a get request with a parameter.

The problem is that I have no idea how to set the parameter from within the app. I have tried

```
.get('https://.../questions', {params: {gender: $scope.user.gender}})
.get('https://.../questions', {params: {gender: user.gender}})
.get('https://.../questions', {params: {gender: vm.user.gender}})
```

The only thing which works is:

.get('https://.../questions', {params: {gender: 'Male'}})

Bigger code snippet below to give some context.

```
 .state('questionnaire', {
    url: '/questionnaire',
    templateUrl: 'templates/questionnaire.html',
    controller: "QuestionnaireController as vm",
    resolve: {
      practice:  function($http){
        return $http
          .get('https://.../...')
          .then (function (data) {
            return data;
          });
      }
    }
  })
  .state('questionnaire.consent', {
    url: '/consent',
    templateUrl: 'templates/questionnaire-consent.html'
  })
  .state('questionnaire.questions', {
    url: '/questions',
    templateUrl: 'templates/questionnaire-questions.html',
    resolve: {
      questions:  function($http, $scope) {
        return $http


  // Failed Attempts
  //      .get('https://.../questions', {params: {gender: $scope.user.gender}})
  //      .get('https://.../questions', {params: {gender: $scope.user.gender}})
  //      .get('https://.../questions', {params: {gender: user.gender}})
  //      .get('https://.../questions', {params: {gender: vm.user.gender}})

  // Works but incorrectly hard coded

  //      .get('https://.../questions', {params: {gender: 'Male'}})

          .then (
            function (res) {
              console.log(res.data);
              return res;
            },
            function(errors) {
              console.log('Errors', errors);
            }
          );
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$stateParams` service.
It lets you pass parameters to your states, for example you can pass the gender as a parameter:

```
.state('questionnaire.questions', {
  url: '/questions/:gender', // Gender is the parameter.
  templateUrl: 'templates/questionnaire-questions.html',
  resolve: {
    questions:  function($http, $scope, $stateParams) {
      // $stateParams.gender is the gender that was given in the url.
```

You can give the gender as a parameter when using a href: `example.com/questions/male`
or by using the second parameter of `$state.go`: `$state.go('questions', {gender: 'male'});`

Read about it in the [ui-router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing).